# difference between the use of hyphen and camel case (font-size and fontSize) in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I know this is very basic, but it does confuse me a little bit, what is the difference between font-size and fontSize?

Is that true you can use whichever you prefer or is there some rules of applying them accordingly?

Comment: I don't think there is any difference, use any of them..

Comment: font-size is valid CSS, fontSize is invalid CSS but valid in JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

`font-size` would be used in CSS while `fontSize` would be used in JavaScript. This is mainly because hyphenated variable names aren't allowed in JavaScript.

Comment: The CSS name `font-size` can be used in JavaScript, too, as in `document.body.style['font-size']`. But if you wish to use the dot notation for a property, then you need to use a “camelcased” property name: `document.body.style.fontSize`